# How to I bring my sticky navbar in front of the contents on my page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress and bootstrap and I have a a navber that sticks to the top of the page when scrolling, problem is it falls behind some of the contents on the page (see image for reference). How to I get the nabber to always be in front of whatever its scrolls past? Thanks in advance.

[image]

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="91" id="search-nav"></nav>
```

CSS:

```
#search-nav {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Try assigning z-index in #search-nav css rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put a value of `z-index` combined with a defined position (could be `fixed`, `absolute`, `relative` .. ) which is higher than the default `z-index` value of the below elements.

**Source** : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is currently using these values for z indexes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/z-index/

CSS:

```
#search-nav {
    z-index: 1100;
}
```

this should do